# GroupBy and Distinct don't work

Tags: c#, sql, json, linq

I am working on a project in C# and linQ. I want to return a JsonList from the BDD. Everything is fine until I try to group by to have only one times each id (I can use distinct too).
This is the code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessTypeStep()
    {
       var result = from a in db.ProcessTypeStep
       join b in db.ProcessStep on a.ProcessTypeStepId equals b.ProcessTypeStepId
       join c in db.ProcessStepOwner on b.ProcessStepId equals c.ProcessStepId
       join e in db.ProcessTypeStepDesc on a.ProcessTypeStepId equals e.ProcessTypeStepId
       select new { e.ProcessTypeStepId, e.ShortDescription };
       result.Distinct();
       result.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So this code return 1000 lines, I just want to group by ID or use distinct but both of them don't work. Nothing change.

This is the code in SQL ans it's working :

```
select a.ProcessTypeStepId,e.ShortDescription
from ProcessTypeStep a
INNER join ProcessStep b on a.ProcessTypeStepId = b.ProcessTypeStepId
INNER  join ProcessStepOwner c on b.ProcessStepId = c.ProcessStepId   
INNER JOIN ProcessTypeStepDesc e on e.ProcessTypeStepId =a.ProcessTypeStepId
GROUP BY a.ProcessTypeStepId,e.ShortDescription
```

Comment: You have to use http://www.linqpad.net/ in order to get SQL and debug it.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You're not doing anyting with the result of `GroupBy` or `Distinct`.  You need something like `result = resut.Distinct().GroupBy(...);`

Comment: Ok Andreas, it was for help, last time I wrote a tag in my title.
And thank you juharr, you have right, it return a new variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`result.Distinct()` for instance returns a new object, but doesn't alter the original `result`. This statement is therefore useless if you don't assign it or pass it to something. The same goes for `GroupBy` or `ToList`. Replace:

```
result.Distinct();
result.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

With:

```
return Json(result.Distinct().GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or at least, assign the returned value of the LINQ ops to a variable:

```
result = result.Distinct();
result = result.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thank a lot the "result = result.Distinct();" is working. But not : "result = result.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();"

Comment: What's not working in this statement ? Does it return an error ?

Comment: The error : + $ {Exception "Error serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set in the maxJsonLength property."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}.

I think it is not in a good format.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ operations produce immutable variations on their inputs, rather than changing the input objects themselves, so these two lines of code do nothing by themselves:

```
   result.Distinct();
   result.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
```

Instead, you can capture the results of each operation:

```
   var distinctResult = result.Distinct();
   var groupedResult = distinctResult.GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
   return Json(groupedResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
result = result.Distinct().GroupBy(w => w.ProcessTypeStepId).ToList();
```

Using just result.Distinct() doesn't modify the list, it returns a new list.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this may work Give it a shot Thanks...:)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessTypeStep()
    {
       var result = from a in db.ProcessTypeStep
       join b in db.ProcessStep on a.ProcessTypeStepId equals         b.ProcessTypeStepId
       join c in db.ProcessStepOwner on b.ProcessStepId equals     c.ProcessStepId
       join e in db.ProcessTypeStepDesc on a.ProcessTypeStepId equals     e.ProcessTypeStepId
group by new
    {
        a.ProcessTypeStepId,
        e.ShortDescription
    } into GBC
select new { GBC.ProcessTypeStepId, GBC.ShortDescription };
result.Distinct();
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```